# Access datas from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe

```
 A           B
Joe         20
Raul        22
James       30
```

How can i create sentence in the following format

```
Mark of Joe is 20
Mark of Raul is 22
Mark of James is 30
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and add an minimal working example to show us what you have tried so far. We are not here to sovle your homework.

Answer (score 3):

For `Series` join values by `+` with casting to strings numeric column(s):

```
s = 'Mark of ' + df.A + ' is ' + df.B.astype(str)
print (s)
0      Mark of Joe is 20
1     Mark of Raul is 22
2    Mark of James is 30
dtype: object
```

If need loop:

```
for x in df[['A','B']].to_numpy(): #df.to_numpy() if only A,B columns
    print (f'Mark of {x[0]} is {x[1]}')

Mark of Joe is 20
Mark of Raul is 22
Mark of James is 30
```

Answer (score 0):

First we replicate your dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['Joe', 'Raul', 'James'], 'B': [20, 22, 30]})
```

Then we can make a new column to the datframe containing the sentences you want

```
df['sentence'] = 'Mark of ' + df.A + ' is ' + df.B.astype(str)
```

Finally we check that the "sentence" column contains the sentence in the format you wanted

```
df
A     B     sentence
Joe   20    Mark of Joe is 20
Raul  22    Mark of Raul is 22
James 30    Mark of James is 30
```